# Creating a smooth jump animation

Tags: python, game-physics

I have some basic jump code.  Once the player hits the space bar, the player will start jumping, and their `jumpCount` will be set to 20.  `jumpCount` is decremented along with the player's y until it reaches -20.  The main problem with this code is that after the player jumps they will end up slightly lower each time they reach the ground.

```py
y = 100
jumpCount = 20

while True:
    if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
        isJump = True

    if isJump:
        if jumpCount >= -20:
            neg = 1 
            if jumpCount < 0:  
                neg = -1

            y -= (jumpCount ** 2) * 0.05 * neg
            jumpCount -= 1

        else:
            jumpCount = 20
            isJump = False
```

Comment: Your question's wording could use a little work. A clearer explanation/example/picture would be very useful.

Comment: @MichaelBianconi What?  Mashing the spacebar would only set the `isJump` value to True, which a check is being run for anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was confused by this before, but there is a solution: try to line it to the landing surface, change it before screen update, so people don't notice it, it will look like it move a bit shorter( really small amount).
for example:

```
if player.x < surface.x:
 player.x = surface.x
update()
```

Little extra:

if you want gravity to work, you can use similar way to do that, on hitting any surface, set grav to 0 and change player's x axis to surface's x axis